# static_cast<T&&>(t) faster than std::forward<T>(t) for compilation?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Recently, I've read a commit comment from range-v3 here:
https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/commit/a4829172c0d6c43687ba213c54f430202efd7497

The commit message says,

> marginally improve compile times by replacing std::forward with
>   static_cast

I know that `std::forward<T>(t)` returns `static_cast<T&&>(t)`, by standard.
Also I do know sometimes `static_cast<T&&>(t)` will work fine when `T &&t` is universial referece(or forwarding reference) by reference collapsing rule.

What I'm interested in is the commit message says that `static_cast` improves marginally compile performance. If `std::forward<T>(t)` just returns `static_cast<T&&>(t)`, what makes such differerence in compile performance?

Maybe does `std::forward<T>(t)` require some kind of deduction anyway? Or, Does `std::forward<T>(t)` do some magical thing which throttles compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you do `std::forward<T>(t)`, the compiler has to instantiate several templates: `std::forward` itself has two overloads, as well as `remove_reference` which is part of the function's signature. And while these templates don't generate much code, it still has to do the work of template instantiation.

For most code, this would be essentially a rounding error in compile time. But for Ranges TS, with all of the forwarding of stuff they do there, it could be non-trivial (though still "marginal").

Comment: It's more than that. It has to instantiate **two** function templates (because `forward` is overloaded), and the `remove_reference` class template, and then do overload resolution.